# htaccess htpasswd session expiration

Tags: authentication, .htaccess, http

I am working with a newsletter site where a username and password set from htaccess and htpasswd is sent out to subscribers for access to a specific page where content is hosted.

I'm interested in finding a way to set a duration for session expiration of the login i.e. 365 days as it seems to be logging out every 8 hours or so from mobile browsers but not desktop browsers.

Here is My htaccess code:

```
<FilesMatch "feed.html">
    AuthName "Member Only"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /home/j1pcvh2gabtn/public_html/.htpasswd
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 3 days"
    require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

I have tried researching htaccess htpasswd expiration and haven't run into anyone else with a similar problem so I'm asking here. The ExpiresActive and ExpiresByType appear to have no effect on how long the session lasts on a mobile device browser. Any ideas why this would happen?

Comment: If you are getting an internal server error, then go check what the error log has to say about it.